# How to track GET requests made to external sites

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, flash, statistics

I'm building a ad click logging plugin.

I need to some find out when the ads are clicked. I have noticed that when the ads start playing there is always a GET request being made to some specific page.

Now I use google chrome's developers tool to see all of the requests being made on my local computer.

Does anyone have any idea of how I can do this and then send the data back to my server?

Answer (score 1):

When the requests made as a result to clicking on an ad are done using ajax you can bind a handler to that ajax event and send information about that click back to your server. See: http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events

For ads using direct http links to load their target you can add a handler to the click event on those anchors, for example using jquery. See: http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: +1 from me. I guess I am old-school in the way that I handle ads and how I intrepret them :)

Comment: @Fluffeh Sure, got that. However the OP writes that he notices get request to other servers. This suggests that he does not do the ad handling himself.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to create a link to a PHP file that you have, that tracks the link that was clicked - stores the data in a database or whatever you want to do with it - then redirects to the URL that the advertisement points to.

What you want is a process flow like this:

`user clicks ad -> runs your PHP code, which saves the data (such as ID of ad clicked, URL being sent to, IP of the person clicking etc etc etc) -> redirects user to the intended destination`

Comment: You didn't get his question. his problem is not to store the counted values, but to react on a users click in the browser that refers to an url on some other server. What you sketch means he would have to rewrite all add urls which might actually get loaded by the client side.